# The mandatory 'Content-Type' header is missing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, openiddict

I was working on asp.net web api and used OpenIdDict as a way to add authorization. I got some problems, which I quickly resolved, but got stuck on one. Whenever I call the Exchange from the controller, it returns 400 and a response body:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The mandatory 'Content-Type' header is missing.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2081"
}
```

I have experimented and searched more and found out, that the 1 part causing the problem is this:

```
        [HttpPost("~/connect/token")]
        [Produces("application/json", "application/vnd.my.v1+json")]
```

the post runs as intended, but the 'produces' can't define the content-type for the request and that's why I get an error. Even know all this, I don't know how to resolve the error. I have even re-tested an already working project and the same error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i did when i tried to test my api to authorize using postman.

1. In the body choose data type as

> x-www-form-urlencoded

[image: body type - form url encoded]

2. and set content type in the headers to

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

[image: headers - content type]

Comment: I have it exactly like this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Cimbir what is the error that you got? do you mind to share some more additional details to exactly know the problem?

Comment: I'm using the OpenIdDict Exchange method, which looks like this: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Hollastin/Hollastin.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs. If it will make the process easier, I can send you the copy of the project. It's not confidential.

Comment: @Cimbir try to apply this on your controller -> Produces("application/json")

Comment: your previous advice didn't work. However, I noticed, that when I create the Authorization Client, it does not add to the OpenIdDictApplications table in the SQL server. This might be the reason why when I get a token and log in, I can't use the other services, which need authorization. If we can somehow sort that out, I think the problem will be resolved. Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Cimbir ok seems like specific to OpenIddict setup. if you could share your code with me privately, I could check to help solve your problem. But that should not be very difficult to add records to the table. Review the configurations for OpenIddict sql connection setup.

Comment: I checked the configurations and sadly couldn't find anything. Tell me where it would be a convenient place for me to send the copy of the project?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue using OpenIdDict with **Swagger**. To fix it you can add operation filter to connect/token request in the following way:
In `services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>`  you should add filter:                 `c.OperationFilter<TokenRequestOperationFilter>();`
Now create `TokenRequestOperationFilter.cs`

```
public class TokenRequestOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.RelativePath.Equals("connect/token", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            operation.Parameters.Clear(); // Clear existing parameters
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "Content-Type",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Required = true,
                Example = new OpenApiString("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This will add Content-Type header to connect/token request.

Also, you can add `grant_type`, `scope` etc in the request body in the following way:

```
operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody
            {
                Required = true,
                Content =
                {
                    ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                    {
                        Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Type = "object",
                            Required = new HashSet<string> { "grant_type", "username", "password", "scope" }, // Mark fields as required
                            Properties =
                            {
                                ["grant_type"] = new OpenApiSchema
                                {
                                    Type = "string",
                                    Default = new OpenApiString("password") 
                                },
                                ["username"] = new OpenApiSchema
                                {
                                    Type = "string",                                    
                                },
                                ["password"] = new OpenApiSchema
                                {
                                    Type = "string",
                                },
                                ["scope"] = new OpenApiSchema
                                {
                                    Type = "string",
                                    Default = new OpenApiString("offline_access") 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```